# How to make any view background transparent?

Tags: android

Attribute of `RelativeLayout android:background="@android:color/transparent"` is not working . I just want to make its background transparent?

Answer (score 19):

Try this:

`android:background="@null"`

Comment: Sorry it dint worked. No Brother i want a transparent background so that my background activity will be visible at the back.

Comment: @VivekCoder Sorry, then I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Could you show us a picture of the problem?

Comment: @Vivek Coder: Can you please share the solution? I am also trying to make this work.

Comment: @Vivek Can you please share the solution?

Answer (score 12):

you can also set it in your java file like this:

```
 view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: Thanx but its not good to set the properties of view programmatically. i need a solution without using styles.xml. I just want to set background property and make it transparent but i failed.

Comment: RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)  findViewById(R.id.yourrelativelayoutid);
 rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

Comment: No No it wont work we have to set a theme through the style.xml which is the only ultimate solution for it. i failed to do this without using style. Solution is as follows:<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" />
    
       <style name="Theme.Translucent" parent="android:style/Theme.Translucent">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/images</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:colorForeground">#fff</item>
    </style> set this as the Theme of activity as: android:theme="@style/Theme.Translucent" we are done:)

Comment: i think above will help those who are indulged i this problem like me--keep on coding

Comment: When I use any other color ( say `setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)` ), it works just fine. but when I change it to transparent ( `setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)` ), it takes about 1 second to change the color. Any idea why this is happening ?

Answer (score 5):

Try this as colour code

```
android:background="#00000000"
```

Comment: Why not use @android:color/transparent instead #00000000?

Answer (score 4):

for your layout set

```
android:background="#00000000"
```

## 00 - Red

00 - Green
00 - Blue
00 - Opacity/Alpha....to specify transparency

for eg. :- #FF000050 will give you red color with 50% transparency

Comment: Is this right? I think Android uses the first two as the alpha (#AARRGGBB), and the transparency is in hex, too, so 50% would be #7FFF0000.

Comment: As @DavidJohnWelsh said `#FF000050` will NOT give you red color with 50% transparency.

Comment: the first 2 are the alpha.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
android:background="#0000"
```

Comment: Why not use @android:color/transparent instead #0000?

Comment: The valid syntax is #AARRGGBBAA 
AA = Alpha
RR = Red 
GG = Green 
BB = Blue 
which should make a completely transparent black #00000000

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into the same situation. you could use this theme for your activity:

```
@android:style/Theme.Translucent
```

then set the view background color

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you said you have an activity in the background, you should be using a fragment for this. If you're using a fragment, just set thr framelayout to transparent background, or don't set it at all, I think this should work as well, your fragment would be on top of the other layout.

If you use

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
```

Then it just adds it on top of the previous one, doesn't replace it like .replace() does.
If you want an activity to be on top of another activity, that is not possible, as there can be only one activity alive at one time.

Comment: Edited to explain.